# How do I find out if a input element's value is blank (null)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have following code to check if the `inputs` with the `ids` `emailForm` and `nameForm` are blank, this however isn't working when I test the form by leaving it blank.

```
 function setInfo() {
    if (document.getElementById("emailForm").value == null || 
    document.getElementById("nameForm").value == null) {

        alert("Please Fill in all sections");

    } else {

    email = document.getElementById("emailForm").value;
    name = document.getElementById("nameForm").value;
    loaded();

    }
}
```

Could someone help me with this, thanks!

Comment: who is calling this function?

Comment: Check for `""`. Or do a `!foo`, which checks for `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`
 etc (but attention, it also checks for `0`, and in some situations `0` is a valid input...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking for `null` specifically, you should check for falsy values. In some cases, the values for empty textboxes will be an empty string.

Replace this:

```
if (document.getElementById("emailForm").value == null || document.getElementById("nameForm").value == null) {
```

with this:

```
if (!document.getElementById("emailForm").value || !document.getElementById("nameForm").value) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be checking whether the fields are `null`, you should be checking whether they content is an empty string (with `.value == ''`).

This can be seen working in the following:

```js
function setInfo() {
  if (document.getElementById("emailForm").value == '' ||
    document.getElementById("nameForm").value == '') {
    console.log("Please fill in all sections");
  } else {
    email = document.getElementById("emailForm").value;
    name = document.getElementById("nameForm").value;
    //loaded();
    console.log("All sections filled in");
  }
}

const button = document.getElementById('go');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  setInfo();
});
```

```html
<input id="emailForm" />
<input id="nameForm" />

<button id="go">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you calling function `setInfo()`

```
function setInfo() {

    // You can check Value.Length also or 
    if (document.getElementById("emailForm").value === "" ||
        document.getElementById("nameForm").value === "") {

        alert("Please Fill in all sections");

    } else {

        email = document.getElementById("emailForm").value;
        name = document.getElementById("nameForm").value;

        loaded();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below solution:**

```
function setInfo() {

var email=document.getElementById("emailForm").value;
var name=document.getElementById("nameForm").value;

if (email=='' || email==null || name=='' || name== null ) { // OR if (!email || !name)

    alert("Please Fill in all sections");
    return;

  } else {
     loaded();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the string is empty or not instead of null. Try using the code below:

```
function setInfo() {


var a=document.getElementById("emailForm").value;
var b=document.getElementById("nameForm").value;
if (a == "" || 
b == "") {

alert("Please Fill in all sections");

} else {

email = 
document.getElementById("emailForm").value;
name = 
document.getElementById("nameForm").value;
alert("success alert");

}
}
```